# Ionic 3 & Android 8: Battery optimiszition is blocking the notifications for Android version 8 and above

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

it’s been a serious problem. I don’t know how the other developers over there implementing the push notifications on China based phones with Android version 8 and above.

I’m using **[cordova-fcm-plugin](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm)** to implement push notifications on the client side and FCM on the server side to trigger the notifications. Everything was working fine till Android version 7. For Android version 8 and above, in few China phones like **One Plus, Oppo, Xiomi** etc they have introduced a feature called Battery Optimization. By default all the the apps installed are battery optimized.

Because of this, if the app is killed by swiping from the app tray. Then app will not receive any push notifications. But popular apps like **WhatsApp, Gmail, Skype** etc are white labeled by these Mobile manufacturers, so they will continue to receive notifications even when app is killed.

If I go to **settings -> Batter -> Battery Optimization** and select the app and chose not to optimize then notifications will be received even when app is killed. But I cannot ask users to do this. I want a programmatic solution to this.

Please let me know, how can I achieve this ? 
Note: I have tried cordova-plugin-doze-Optimize already, but no change.

Answer (score 1):

Fist off, you shouldn't use that plugin, it hasn't been updated in two years, but android apis have long since been updated. [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase) is more actively maintained.

Also, it depends on notification priority. If your device has gone to sleep, it will not receive low priority notifications until woken up manually. Notification priority can also be set server-side:

```
"android":{   
    "priority":"high"
  },
"apns":{
    "headers":{
      "apns-priority":"10"
    }
  }
```

Comment: So you are able to get notifications on China based phones whose Android version is 8 and above, with this settings ?

Comment: Yes? I'm not sure why Chinese hardware producers are such a concern to you. Samsung, Sony etc. have also introduced battery optimization in their recent versions. The hardware spec is not the issue, but the version of Android you're on. Also, Android OS receives the notification, not your app. Your app can be killed, sleeping or whatever, you will still receive push notifications. This is purely based on priority.

Comment: Not really, with cordova-fcm-plugin just by setting "priority":"high" on the payload, notifications are not getting delivered. I'm specific to chines phones because, when I go to battery settings and chose my app not to optimize, then notifications starts working. Now I will try with cordova-plugin-firebase and update you the status.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that some manufacturers (Xiaomi, Oppo, One Plus, Huawei, ...) have customize the android firmware. 
Basically, if you kill an app from the "recently open" screen, you're killing the background process. 
Unfortunately, with custom firmware applications are unable to restart automatically due to battery optimization. 
This lead us to delayed or blocked notifications. 
It seems that this functionnality can't be disabled programmatically. So no real others solution than do a homemade page to explain to user how desactivate battery optimization manually.
This article explain with a better english than mine the all process. 
[It looks like there is no solutions](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/why-your-push-notifications-never-see-the-light-of-day-3fa297520793/) 
But in the same time, looking the firebase cloud messaging documentation :
[Cloud messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

> **High priority.**  FCM attempts to deliver high priority messages immediately, allowing the FCM service to wake a sleeping device when necessary and to run some limited processing (including very limited network access). High priority messages generally should result in user interaction with your app or its notifications. If FCM detects a pattern in which they don't, your messages may be de-prioritized. Android P introduced [app standby buckets](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/power-details)which limit the number of FCM high priority messages you can send to your app that don't result in the user using your app or viewing a notification. If, in response to a high priority message, a notification is displayed in a way that is visible to the user, then your app standby bucket quota will not be consumed by that message.

Then, in my case after testing, the following server code fixe the issue on my one plus 6.

```
        android: {
          priority: 'high',
        },
        apns: {
          headers: {
            'apns-priority': '10',
          },
        },
```

But keep in mind that:

"High priority messages generally should result in user interaction with your app or its notifications. If FCM detects a pattern in which they don't, your messages may be de-prioritized." so we should be careful with this priority

Answer (score 0):

I thank people who answered to my question. What finally worked for me was, releasing the app to google play store. Whenever I tried installing debug/signed app which is generated from the Ionic CLI, China based devices like Oppo, One Plus etc, were not receiving the notifications. So I followed below approach.

1. Debug/Signed apps generated from development environment is not trusted by these manufacturers, because of that when you are app is killed from background state all the tasks associated with it will be ended. Due to this reason even you will not be able to receive notifications.
2. I had my older version of the app on play store, when user installs app from store they were receiving the notifications on all China based phones and other phones too.
3. So First I made a beta release of the new version of the app tested the app across multiple China based phones by downloading it. Fortunately notifications were working fine.
4. After that I rolled out the actual release. Whola, everything works fine now.